# Is there a way to update a custom field in Wordpress with a front-end file upload?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, file-upload, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to update a custom WordPress-field with a file upload from a front-end form.

Example:

```
<form action="submit"><input type="file" name="file_upload"><button type="submit">Submit</button></form>
```

Now I am looking for the php code that updates the custom field (file upload) in WordPress named 'file_upload' of a post with a certain ID. The plugin I use is 'Advanced Custom Fields'.

EDIT:
I get the file via an $_FILES request in PhP:

```
$file_upload = $_FILES['file_upload'];
```

Then I try to handle the upload via this method:

```
$file_upload_id = media_handle_upload( $file_upload, 0 );
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to upload your file into your upload directory
then you can use this function to update file path. [ACF update Field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/)

```
update_field( 'file_upload', $file_path_value, $post_id );
```

Go through this [PHP File Upload](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) tutorial it may helps you to upload file.

I am setting up a basic example here so just you can get an idea.

```
$wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir() // Use Wordpres wp_upload_dir() to get proper URL and path 
$target_dir = $wp_upload_dir['basedir'];
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file_upload"]["name"]);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_upload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file_upload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    update_field( 'file_upload', $target_file, $post_id );
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
```

I have not tested this code, but you can get the basic idea from it

Comment: Thanks. But how do I get the value from my upload field in jquery (to pass via ajax)? I am using $(input[name="file_upload"].val(); Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, You can.
You have to correct jquery selector please check below code and make change in your code.

$("input[name=file_upload]").prop('files');

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work. $("input[name=file_upload]")[0].files[0]; also seems to work (it only returns one file object). Now do I have to add a new FormData() in my jquery in order to pass the arguments (as seen on other forums)?

Comment: Yes, You just need to append file object to your FormData().

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has a build in upload function that returns the attachment id you need to update the field, its recommended to use a nonce field to verify it's the right place.

```
    if ( 
        isset( $_POST['my_image_upload_nonce'], $_POST['post_id'] ) 
        && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['my_image_upload_nonce'], 'my_image_upload' )
    ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
        $attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'my_image_upload', $_POST['post_id'] );
        if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
            update_field('image', $attachment_id, $_POST['post_id']);
        } else {
       // The image was uploaded successfully!
    }

    } else {

    // The security check failed, maybe show the user an error.
    }
```